# Angular Custom RouteReuseStrategy retrieve method fails with Error: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I'm trying to achieve tab like feature in my angular application.

For that, I created a custom Angular `RouteReuseStrategy` and query parameter passed to identify the respective page handle on the retrieve. On switch between the same base page but parameter different, then retrieve method fails.

For example on the employee page, I need to have more than one copy of the `DetachedRouteHandle` of employee form to switch between in my SPA.

```js
import * as rootStateSaveActions from '../../store/actions/rootStateSave.action';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RouteTabs } from '../../store/models/pageTab.model';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@Injectable()
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    savedRoutes$: Observable<RouteTabs>;
    RouteTabs: RouteTabs;

    constructor(private ngrxStore: Store<RouteTabs>, private injector: Injector) {
        this.savedRoutes$ = ngrxStore.select('saveState');
        this.savedRoutes$.subscribe((state) => {
            this.RouteTabs = state;
        });
    };

    handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // call when leave the current route
        // TRUE will invoke store method
        // Determine if this route should be detached to be resued later
        return !!route.data && !!(route.data as any).shouldDetach;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        // store the detached route
        let pageNo: string = (route.queryParamMap.get('pageNo') == null) ? new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString() : route.queryParamMap.get('pageNo');
        this.handlers[pageNo] = handle;
        // ----------ngrx store used to save the page visited details
        let urlName: string = route.data.urlName;
        this.ngrxStore.dispatch(new rootStateSaveActions.CreateSaveRootState({
            // url: route.routeConfig.path,
            url: route.routeConfig.path,
            urlName: urlName,
            handle: null,
            unique: pageNo // used to identify minimized route handle.
        }))
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // This method will call after component
        // Detremine if this route should be reattached
        // If return true "retrieve" method will call
        if (route.routeConfig) {
            return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.queryParamMap.get('pageNo')];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        // retrieve the previously stored route
        if (route.routeConfig) {
            let pageNo: string = route.queryParamMap.get('pageNo');
            if (this.handlers[pageNo] == undefined) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return this.handlers[pageNo];
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // Determine if a route should be resued
        // if it return true routing will not happend
        if (curr.queryParamMap.get('pageNo') != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
    }
}
```

This shows the following error:

> Error: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot created from a different route.